# PayPal REST Api not returning exchange_rate

Tags: paypal

I have got a PayPal Advanced Checkout Sandbox set up and capturing the order using the API call below:

```
/v2/checkout/orders/{{order_id}}/capture
```

Below are the transaction details I send to create the order:

```json
{
    "intent": "CAPTURE",
    "payer": {
        "address": {
            "admin_area_2": "Downton",
            "postal_code": "SP5",
            "country_code": "GB"
        }
    },
    "purchase_units": [
        {
            "description": "Test Item",
            "custom_id": "12345",
            "soft_descriptor": "Purchase Descriptior",
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "58.80",
                "breakdown": {
                    "item_total": {
                        "currency_code": "USD",
                        "value": "49.00"
                    },
                    "tax_total": {
                        "currency_code": "USD",
                        "value": "9.80"
                    }
                }
            },
            "items": [
                {
                    "name": "Test Item",
                    "unit_amount": {
                        "currency_code": "USD",
                        "value": "49.00"
                    },
                    "tax": {
                        "currency_code": "USD",
                        "value": "9.80"
                    },
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "category": "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
                }
            ],
            "shipping": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

And then once it has been paid with a sandbox personal account the order capture response is below:

```json
{
    "id": "4FS9138999682320N",
    "status": "COMPLETED",
    "payment_source": {
        "paypal": {
            "email_address": "sb-bdd43g21513704@personal.example.com",
            "account_id": "V7ZN4NEJRLGZA",
            "name": {
                "given_name": "John",
                "surname": "Doe"
            },
            "address": {
                "country_code": "GB"
            }
        }
    },
    "purchase_units": [
        {
            "reference_id": "default",
            "shipping": {
                "name": {
                    "full_name": "John Doe"
                },
                "address": {
                    "address_line_1": "Whittaker House",
                    "address_line_2": "2 Whittaker Avenue",
                    "admin_area_2": "Richmond",
                    "admin_area_1": "Surrey",
                    "postal_code": "TW9 1EH",
                    "country_code": "GB"
                }
            },
            "payments": {
                "captures": [
                    {
                        "id": "40V95236PS9814847",
                        "status": "COMPLETED",
                        "amount": {
                            "currency_code": "USD",
                            "value": "58.80"
                        },
                        "final_capture": true,
                        "seller_protection": {
                            "status": "ELIGIBLE",
                            "dispute_categories": [
                                "ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED",
                                "UNAUTHORIZED_TRANSACTION"
                            ]
                        },
                        "seller_receivable_breakdown": {
                            "gross_amount": {
                                "currency_code": "USD",
                                "value": "58.80"
                            },
                            "paypal_fee": {
                                "currency_code": "USD",
                                "value": "2.30"
                            },
                            "net_amount": {
                                "currency_code": "USD",
                                "value": "56.50"
                            }
                        },
                        "custom_id": "12345",
                        "links": [
                            {
                                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/40V95236PS9814847",
                                "rel": "self",
                                "method": "GET"
                            },
                            {
                                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/40V95236PS9814847/refund",
                                "rel": "refund",
                                "method": "POST"
                            },
                            {
                                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/4FS9138999682320N",
                                "rel": "up",
                                "method": "GET"
                            }
                        ],
                        "create_time": "2022-10-31T16:42:07Z",
                        "update_time": "2022-10-31T16:42:07Z"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "payer": {
        "name": {
            "given_name": "John",
            "surname": "Doe"
        },
        "email_address": "sb-bdd43g21513704@personal.example.com",
        "payer_id": "V7ZN4NEJRLGZA",
        "address": {
            "country_code": "GB"
        }
    },
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/4FS9138999682320N",
            "rel": "self",
            "method": "GET"
        }
    ]
}
```

I get a status: COMPLETED as the response but it is not returning the exchange_rate value even though the payer currency is different to the payee currency.

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Your question isn't clear, what matters is the transaction currency which is separate from both the payer and the payee. You should include some order creation and capture samples

Comment: Hi Preston, thank you for your response, I have updated the main post with some extra details.

Answer (score 0):

The example is a USD transaction, the payee account received USD.

If the payer used a funding source of a different currency to fund the transaction, this will not be visible to the receiver or API facilitator. Any such sender currency conversion is between the payer and PayPal; all you know (and all you need to know) is you received the requested USD amount via PayPal.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention my payee account is in GBP. My order capture details are always in the currency that the payer sent, it never mentions the GBP I actually received which is the info I need as well as the exchange rate

Comment: PayPal accounts can hold other currencies in addition to the primary

Comment: Yes, but on the REST Api doc the description for the value of exchange_rate says:
"The exchange rate that determines the amount that is credited to the payee's PayPal account. **Returned when the currency of the captured payment is different from the currency of the PayPal account where the payee wants to credit the funds**." Which in my case is correct, but the exchange_rate is still not being returned

Comment: Only applies when the payment receiving preferences of the payee account are set to convert the received funds to the primary currency. Does not apply when no exchange is taking place.

Comment: Ah! Do you know how I would do this with a sandbox account?

Comment: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessmanage/account/money and https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessmanage/preferences/payments